# How can I animate individual elements in recycler view simultaneously

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have been working on recycler view animations and I stumbled upon a great app (Relay) animation example (video link below) which I have been trying to replicate.
I want to animate each layout item simultaneously inside the recycler view but am not able to figure out the approach for this.

Should I create a custom `LayoutManager` that animates the views whenever the item layout is changed or use `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` is there some better approach to achieve something similar?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k7s6.jpg